# Juntar várias tabelas

Tags: python, pandas

Boa tarde,

Por gentileza, poderiam me ajudar? Estou executando o código abaixo:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

symbol ="SPY"
ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
ticker.options
i=0

while i <= 4:
    a = ticker.option_chain(date=ticker.options[i])
    b = a.puts.drop(columns=['contractSymbol','lastTradeDate','bid','ask','change','percentChange','volume','openInterest','impliedVolatility','inTheMoney','contractSize','currency'])
    display(b)
    i+=1
```

E estou enfrentando um problema, pois o python devolve várias tabelas e não consigo unir elas tendo como referência o strike.
[Imagem de Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dKFU.png)

Acrescento abaixo uma versão da tabela que pretendo alcançar. Fiz ela de forma manual.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYGPg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, ficou um pouco confuso o que seria "unir elas com referência o strike". Isso seria agrupar se o strike é o mesmo? O lastPrice seria agrupado como (escolher o maior, somar todos, a média).

Bom, para unir as tabelas, podemos criar um DataFrame pelo pandas e dar um append nele. Como não sei como pretende agrupar, coloquei uma abaixo da outra.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

symbol ="SPY"
ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)

table = pd.DataFrame()
for date in ticker.options:
    a = ticker.option_chain(date=date)
    b = a.puts.drop(columns=['contractSymbol','lastTradeDate','bid','ask','change','percentChange','volume','openInterest','impliedVolatility','inTheMoney','contractSize','currency'])
    table = table.append(b, ignore_index=True)

display(table)
```

Ao final, vamos ter uma única tabela (que chamei de table) com todos os strikes e lastPrice.

> Vale dizer que coloquei todas as datas (`ticker.options`), mas se quiser escolher apenas as primeiras 4 (como fez no seu código) substitua o `for date in ticker.options:` para `for date in ticker.options[:4]:`

Caso deseje fazer uma união diferente da que fiz, recomendo o seguinte link: https://medium.com/data-hackers/pandas-combinando-data-frames-com-merge-e-concat-10e7d07ca5ec

[Resultado final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGwN0.png)

---

**Edit**

Após o novo exemplo, consegui entender melhor qual é a ideia. Acredito que o código abaixo resolva:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

symbol ="SPY"
ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)

table = pd.DataFrame()
for date in ticker.options:
    a = ticker.option_chain(date=date)
    b = a.puts.drop(columns=['contractSymbol','lastTradeDate','bid','ask','change','percentChange','volume','openInterest','impliedVolatility','inTheMoney','contractSize','currency'])
    
    b.set_index('strike', inplace=True)
    b.columns = [date]

    table = pd.concat([table, b], axis=1)

display(table)
```

Comment: Boa noite. Em primeiro lugar agradeço pela disposição em ajudar. Eu editei a pergunta para incluir um modelo da planilha que pretendo alcançar. A ideia não é colocar uma embaixo da outra, mas sim, ao lado.

Comment: @JhonyLucas adicionei um edit que talvez ajude!

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou bastante.

Comment: Se possível, adicione como "resposta aceita"  para que pessoas que tem problemas similares ao seu encontrem rapidamente a resposta. @JhonyLucas